# Remove backslashes with sed command in a file

Tags: linux, sed

I have a file like this:

```
'AAA' 'a\\\\b\\\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
...
```

And I want to replace all occurrences of `\\\\` with `\\`.

I tried this sed command:

```
sed 's/\\//g'
```

but this removes all `\`.

This is my output:

```
'AAA' 'aba'
'BBB' 'qls'
```

The output I want:

```
'AAA' 'a\\b\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
...
```

Comment: In "the output I want", the BBB line is equivalent to the input. Is this desired or a typo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Replaces sequences of 4 backslashes with 2 backslashes:**

```
sed 's/\\\\\\\\/\\\\/g' input.txt
```

**Alternatively, use  `{4}` to indicate how many `\` are matched:**

```
sed 's/\\\{4\}/\\\\/g' input.txt
```

**input.txt**

```
'AAA' 'a\\\\b\\\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
```

**output**

```
'AAA' 'a\\b\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
```

---

You must *escape* special regex characters like `\` with another `\`.

`{` and `}` are also regex characters, however the *ed*-like tools (ed,vim,sed,...) don't recognize them as such by default. To use curly-braces to specify a regex count (e.g., `{4}`), sed requires you escape them (e.g., `\{4\}`)

So...

- escape `\` to use it literally; not as a regex character
- escape `{` and `}` to use them as regex characters rather than literal braces

Comment: The reason you need to escape { and } isn't that they appear frequently, so do `.`s and `(`s, etc. The reason is they are historically ERE metacharacters, not BRE, just like `+` and `?`. If you enable EREs with `-E` then you don't need to escape them.

Answer (score 3):

With any sed that supports EREs, e.g. GNU or AIX seds:

```
$ sed -E 's/(\\){4}/\\\\/' file
'AAA' 'a\\b\\\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to replace all '\\\\' to '\\'

Use the following approach:

```
sed 's/\\\\\\\\/\\\\/g' file
```

The output:

```
'AAA' 'a\\b\\a\\'
'BBB' 'q\\l\\s\\'
```

---

each backslash `\` should be escaped with ... backslash :)

Comment: sorry this is what i want I want to replace all '\\\\' to '\\', my mistake i edited the questions